# WPF Radio Button IsChecked not working

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have two radio buttons and I want one to be selected by default. I added `IsChecked="true"` , but it doesn't work. I also tryed to set it in the window load.

But when I click the second option and then click the first option, everything works fine.

It just doesn't show up clicked at first load.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 3 0 0" Height="55">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="True" Padding="1 1 0 10" Name="AutoSaveRadioButton">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Auto Save Test File</TextBlock>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Margin="0 1 0 0" Padding="1 1 3 1" Name="SaveFileTogetherRadioButton">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Save Test File &amp; <LineBreak /> output file together</TextBlock>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I simply copied and pasted your XAML into a newly created WPF project and ran it. The first radio button is selected, so I'm unable to reproduce your problem. This is with .NET 4.0.

Comment: hmmm. Yeah.... Well.. I suspect it has to do with the theme I'm using ? Im using the BureauBlack theme I found in the wpf community.

Comment: Unless you post some more information there isn't much to go on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the theme you're using is [this one](https://github.com/StanislawSwierc/WpfThemesCollection/blob/master/Themes/BureauBlack.xaml), it looks like a bug with the theme. The `Trigger` on line 687 only fires when the `IsChecked` property changes to `False`, but the initial state of the template is un-checked.

Try changing the trigger to reverse the behaviour:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOff}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOn}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```